# npgsql - use one connection to access multiple schemas

Tags: c#, npgsql

I want to create an application where each customer's data is stored in its own schema, where the tables in each schema are the same.

I thought it will be cheaper to use schemas instead of databases, because with schemas only one connection needs to be established to the database to reach all customer schemas.

But I'm not sure how I can achieve this using npgsql. Is there a way to create some sort of Schema Contexts for a connection, which then has the same api as the original connection?

I imagine something like this:

```
NpgsqlConnection con =  new NpgsqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING");
con.Open();

SchemaContext customer1 = con.createSchemaContext("customer1");
SchemaContext customer2 = con.createSchemaContext("customer2");

customer1.Query("select * from users");
customer2.Query("select * from users");
```

Is there already something like this, or is there a way to implement this myself?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question isn't related to Npgsql in any way - it's a PostgreSQL question.

PostgreSQL does support schemas, you can Google about it. In a nutshell you create schemas, then create tables within them, and then access those tables thus: `SELECT * FROM customer1.users`. Npgsql doesn't provide any programmatic API beyond this since it (mostly) doesn't touch the SQL you send to PostgreSQL.

Note that if the tables in each of your imagined schemas have the same columns (and I'm imagining they probably do), then you are probably better off having one table and distinguish between different customers via a "customer" column.